# prepareForSegue not passing appropriate row in tableView

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a Table View with Lessons and want to pass lesson's name in detail view controller. But it always passes the first row.

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewRowAction *edit = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"edit" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editLesson" sender:nil];
    }];



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editLesson"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedLesson = [self.lessons objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        EditLessonViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.lesson = selectedLesson;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass indexPath as sender in performSegue.
There is yours code:

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewRowAction *edit = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"edit" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editLesson" sender:indexPath];
    }];



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editLesson"]) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
        NSManagedObject *selectedLesson = [self.lessons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        EditLessonViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.lesson = selectedLesson;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just about to say use iVars but this is neat. You cannot rely on table.indexPathForSelectedRow to get rows that are being edited.